# Invalid CSS property declaration at:

Tags: html, css

I'm getting this message in the error console of safari:
Invalid CSS property declaration at .
Any idea what the issue is? 
Thanks,

[image]

Comment: Maybe you've not closed the previous property.

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...
animation: ani-mouse 2.5s linear infinite;

} <-- closing bracket is missing
```

the previous css section is missing a closing bracket, thus causing the next line to be wrong.